# Export Plotted Image to Excel

Tags: excel, image, plot, copy

Good afternoon fellow R users. I have a question revolving around my plots.

Is there a method to copy a plot to an excel document as an image? I've got a wordcloud built out in my plots with an export to a separate .png file already built in, but I'd like to copy my wordcloud directly into my final excel document as well. My code to export my various word-grams is as follows:

```
temp <- inspect(tdm_quadgram)
freqmat <- data.frame(Quadgram=rownames(temp),Word_Count=rowSums(temp))
row.names(freqmat) <- NULL
freqmat <- freqmat[order(-temp),]
write.xlsx(freqmat, file = output_file, sheetName = "QuadraGrams", 
           row.names = F, append = T)
```

Is there a similar way to "write" an image to a separate excel tab?

Thank you!

Comment: A quick and dirty way (for windows users) is to use snipping tool to take a "screenshot" of the output, as it will save as a jpeg you can copy and paste that into your excel file.

Comment: I've been doing that. I've been taking a screen shot of my wordcloud, then using MS Paint (I know. Its terrible.), I've just copy/pasted my wordcloud into the appropriate tab, but I'd love to just do it all at once with my R code.

My image creation code is as follows:

`dev.copy(png,filename=output_wcloud)`

I've already got a separate file created. I just want to put that image into the excel file I create as well.

Thanks!